# Simple jquery plugin to insert special characters into textarea field (non-Editor)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, utf-8, character-encoding

Does anyone know of a simple jquery plugin to allow special characters such as ½, ¼, ¾, Õ, ™ etc. (UTF-8 only) to be inserted into a textarea field?

I was thinking of writing it myself, but I thought I'd ask here first. I can't seem to find anything thru Google searching. I'd need a modal to allow someone to select a special character and then inset that into a textarea. This would be purely text based UTF-8 character encoding. HTML editors such as CKEditor, TinyMCE, Markitup can not be used as they are too complex for the owner of the system/project.

Comment: If you think of writing a plugin to insert *any* special characters, you might get some ideas from my Full Unicode Input utility, http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8 (which uses UTF-16, so you would need to use a converter if you really need UTF-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html

Comment: Oh, that's slick. Lots of options. I think I may have overlooked that plugin/page during my search. Thank you for the accepted answer.