# Textarea type special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a textarea I want the user to be able to press the letters on their keyboard and type 𝒜ℬ𝒞𝒟 etc. (so typing the &ascr ; &bscr ; special characters)

Is there anyway to do this? And have the user freely being able to edit the characters like in a normal textarea.

The user will be able to click to select a style (which sets my **var style** integer) and the letters will be a different style like 𝔄𝔅ℭ𝔇 (&Afr ; &Bfr ; &Cfr ; etc.)

What I want to achieve at the end is the user typing a paragraph, then the text will appear formatted in that way in the textarea, they could switch styles in between. Then they will be able to copy the text / save it as a .html file.

**Any method is welcome! :)**

Thanks!

.

Example of what the user could type: Hello my name is Friedpanseller!

What the textarea could display: ℋℯ𝓁𝓁ℴ ℳ𝓎 𝒩𝒶𝓂ℯ ℐ𝓈 𝔉𝔯𝔦𝔢𝔡𝔭𝔞𝔫𝔰𝔢𝔩𝔩𝔢𝔯!

**Then the user can delete some words in the middle / edit them like a normal textarea**

Example of what the user could type: My names are Friedpanseller!

What the textarea could display: ℳ𝓎 𝒩𝒶𝓂ℯ𝓈 𝒜𝓇ℯ 𝔉𝔯𝔦𝔢𝔡𝔭𝔞𝔫𝔰𝔢𝔩𝔩𝔢𝔯!

Comment: I think your html page not getting font. is there any error on console?

Comment: I want the user to be able to type it in on the go. I can preset the contents of the textarea to whatever I want but the user cannot type their own paragraph in using the fancy font

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850088/simple-jquery-plugin-to-insert-special-characters-into-textarea-field-non-edito

Comment: Rino I could use that for now but users will get annoyed that they have to click the letters they type. It is slower and more frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the third party tools ( Mostly I prefer to use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)) because its free

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0gp2wnLk/) is an example of what you could do. Type "a" (without quotes) into that text area. It's **not exactly fast**, but it's what I could gather. It doesn't address all of your requests but it's a start.

```
$("textarea").bind("keyup", function() {
    var cursorPosition = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.indexOf('a') > -1) {
        text = text.replace(/a/g, '');
        $(this).val(text);
        $('textarea').prop("selectionStart", cursorPosition - 1);
        $('textarea').prop("selectionEnd", cursorPosition - 1);
    }
});
```

You could try to **apply this systematically for the characters** you want to substitute. Good luck.

Comment: your example works but when I tried it myself it doesn't work for some reason.
I copied exactly what the jsfiddle had into a blank html file and it doesnt change the a when typed
http://friedpanseller.com/test/test.html

Comment: Try adding it directly in the HTML with a `<script></script>` tag, or if that's what you did then try adding it in the `<head>` of your HTML document as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the code in blank html, please add document.ready for jquery event bind.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("textarea").bind("keyup", function() {
    var cursorPosition = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.indexOf('a') > -1) {
        text = text.replace(/a/g, '');
        $(this).val(text);
        $('textarea').prop("selectionStart", cursorPosition - 1);
        $('textarea').prop("selectionEnd", cursorPosition - 1);
    }
});
});
```

It works this way, if we use the same code in separate HTML page.